# is there any way to call parent class method from child class object in java without modifying methods

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have parent class and a child class, both of having a method m1 with same signature (Override), can I call parent class method in following scenario. I dont want to change child class method.

```
// Super class
public class Parent
{
    public void m1()
    {
        System.out.println("Parent method");
    }
}
// Sub class
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("Child method");
    }
}
// User class
public class Kavi {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Parent p = new Child();
            p.m1();

        }
}
```

I want to call parent class m1 method. I know that I can use super in child class method to call its parent method. but I have no right to change the source code of child class. and I have to call it from child class object. please anybody help !!! is it possible in java ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While creating the Object you are using reference of Super class but your object is of child class, so while calling m1() method the overrided method will be invoked. If you want the method of the super class to be invoked then object should be of Super class.  As :

```
Parent parent=new Parent();
parent.m1();
```

**OR**

you can invoke the super class m1() method from the child class.

```
@Override
public void m1() {
    super.m1();
    System.out.println("Child method");
      }
```

**OR ELSE**

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
class A {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("In a");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("In b");
    }
}
class M {
    public static void main( String ... args ) throws Exception {
        A b = new B();
        b.method();
        b.getClass()
     .getSuperclass()
     .getMethod("method", new Class[]{} )
     .invoke(  b.getClass().getSuperclass().newInstance() ,new Object[]{}                  ) ;

}
}
```

Comment: i know these two ways. i have already mentioned in question itself. My query is if there is any other way to call a parent class method

Comment: @kavitemre You can customize the m1() method by passing a parameter may be boolean which can decide whether to call parent method or to execute child method . But there is no other possible way as much as i know.

Comment: @kavi maybe you should rethink your problem, if either of these solutions don't work. Another less appropriate solution would be to use reflection... But I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Charles its a good one , but i think then there will be no overriding , can you elaborate your view

Comment: Using reflection or customizing the m1 method by passing some parameter can do, but that will raise the complexity .

Comment: @CharlesStevens i dont want to change my child class. You were saying about Using reflection. i need that skeleton.

Comment: @kavitemre Updated again !!

Comment: I'm curious why you can't type cast B to A and then call method like so: `((A) b).method()`. I tried this, and it still returns "In b" (rather than "In a"). Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 4):

Without changing the code, you can't do this.  You're essentially talking about `p.super.m1()` which isn't legal in Java.  If you want your parent to act like a parent, don't make it a child.

If both parent and child are stateless, you could create a facade over them and explicitly manage the state;  this would work, but I wouldn't recommend it.

```
public class Facade extends Parent {

    public enum State {PARENT, CHILD};

    private final Child delegate;

    private State state = State.CHILD;

    public Facade(Child delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void m1() {
        if (State.CHILD == state) {
            delegate.m1();
        } else {
            super.m1();
        }
    }

     public void setState(State state) {
         this.state = state;
     }
}
```

This is a purely academic exercise - I can't think of a single good reason to do this in the real world.  If you're using an OO language, don't fight the OO paradigm!

Comment: Steve i try with your class, but it is still calling child class m1 method.

Comment: Did you use setState(Facade.State.PARENT) to switch it to parent mode?

Comment: I have use your class as follows 
      Child ch = new Child();
      Facade f = new Facade(ch);
      f.setState(Facade.State.PARENT);
      f.m1();
but it giving StackOverflow Exception.

Comment: I've edited the code.  It should be `super.m1();` not `this.m1();`

Comment: Yes Steve its working fine. thanks a lot +1 for your out of box solution.

Comment: Please tell me you're not going to use this in production!

Comment: Nice Logic and use of Java features. Salute to your answer

Comment: No Steve, i will not use it in production, this was interview question, i have given two solution one with super.m1() in child class and and another is creating Parent Object  but interviewer was not accepting, He want a out of box solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think it not possible. There are two ways to call a parent class method

1.) crate object of parent class as

**Parent p = new Parent();**

2.) Use **super** in child class method as

```
@Override
    public void m1() {
        super.m1();
        System.out.println("Child method");
    }
```

Comment: i dont want to crate object of Parent class

Comment: @kavitemre then it's not possible , there are only 2 ways !! and you don't want to use either of them .

Comment: @Neeraj Jain i know these two ways. i have already mentioned in question itself. My query is if there is any other way to call a parent class method

Comment: ***No there is no other way*** !

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the already mentioned way, you can declare both the methods as static.

so when you do this
 
`Parent p = new Child();
p.m1();`

the static method of parent class would be called and the output will be "Parent method"

**Note :** The static keyword in Java means that the variable or function is shared between all instances of that class as it belongs to the type, not the actual objects themselves. 
So if you have a variable: 
private static int i = 0; and you increment it ( i++ ) in one instance, the change will be reflected in all instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not use `super` then instead of creating the child class object you can directly use

```
Parent p = new Parent();
p.m1();
```

if you can't even modify the code inside main method then I think it's not possible .

Comment: i dont want to crate object of Parent class. i can alter my main method. also i can create another method if needed.