# subclass and method-How can i call a method from a subclass?

Tags: java

[image]

How can i call a method from a subclass?

Comment: First, please search Google, or this site, preferably both, for your question before asking.

Comment: You can declare the method in SuperA, and implement it in SubB1 and SubB2. Or you can declare the reference variable `obj` to be of type SubB1. Or you can cast to SubB1 before calling, if you know for certain that the object is of type SubB1.

Comment: If your question is `how to access methods in subclass that are not present in parent class`, you need to cast your object to the subclass and access those methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there any way to call parent class method from child class object in java without modifying methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068210/is-there-any-way-to-call-parent-class-method-from-child-class-object-in-java-wit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following will clarify your doubts:

```
class SuperA {
    void superMeth1() {
        System.out.println("superMeth1");
    }

    void superMeth2() {
        System.out.println("superMeth2");
    }
}

class Sub1 extends SuperA {
    void superMeth1() {
        System.out.println("superMeth1_sub1");
    }

    void sub1Meth1() {
        System.out.println("subMeth1");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperA obj = new SuperA();
        obj.superMeth1(); // Prints superMeth1
        obj.superMeth2(); // Prints superMeth2

        obj = new Sub1();
        obj.superMeth1(); // Prints superMeth1_sub1
        //obj.sub1Meth1(); // Compilation error as SuperA does not know about Sub1
        ((Sub1) obj).sub1Meth1(); // Prints subMeth1 because of the cast

        Sub1 sub1 = new Sub1();
        sub1.superMeth1(); // Prints superMeth1_sub1
        sub1.sub1Meth1(); // Prints subMeth1
    }
}
```